# Qt. How can I translate QPageSetupDialog dialog?

Tags: qt, qt-linguist

I need to translate standard Qt QPageSetupDialog that I thought used by QPrintPreviewDialog, but now I am not sure. I was able to translate QPrintPreviewDialog itself by using qtbase_de.qm, I generated it with lrelease and qtbase_de.ts downloaded from qt documentation.

Translated QPrintPreviewDialog, but not QPrintDialog

[image]

Not translated QPageSetupDialog

[image]

There is no translations for QPageSetupDialog actually, only for some QPageSetupWidget

[image]

So am I still able to translate QPageSetupDialog and QPrintDialog?

Comment: The print dialog and page setup dialog look like native system dialogs (Windows). I don't think you can translate them.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will keep it mind, but still will wait for other answers.

Comment: In addition, here is what Qt docs say: "...On Windows and macOS, the native print dialog is used, which means that some QWidget and QDialog properties set on the dialog won't be respected..." http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintdialog.html#details

Comment: Thanks. This sounds more solid. Will wait a day for other opinions and mark your question as answer.